# grails mongodb findBy return null

Tags: mongodb, grails

Im having a problem with grails returning a null value on a single property set in my mongdb. Viewing the collection from the mongo console the value is clearly set to "INFO"

```
....
"name" : "test"
"rules" : [
        {
                "field" : "level",
                "dataType" : "String",
                "value" : "INFO",
                "comparator" : "="
        }
]
....
```

the following will display ok values on all properties except the value field:

```
 def list = TheDomainObject.findByName("test")
 list.rules.get(0).comparator    -> results in return  "="
 list.rules.get(0).field         -> results in return  "level"
 list.rules.get(0).value         -> results in return  null
```

what am i missing, why is the value field returning null ?
The domain is defined as:

```
String field
String comparator
Object value
String dataType

static constraints = {
    field nullable: false, blank: false
    comparator nullable: false, blank: false
    value nullable: false
    dataType nullable: false, blank: false
}
```

running grails 2.1.1 and mongodb 2008plus-2.0.5

Comment: Are you sure that value is an allowed keyword? Never used the mongoDB plugin, so I'm just guessing.

Comment: I think you want to do list.value

Comment: @marko, for what we know the only fields that belong to the list object (why is it called list btw?) are the name and the rules. Looking at list.value does not make any sense to me (unless it's something strictly related to how mongoDB works, but honestly I don't think so.. correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I'm afraid I have no experience with mongoDB, but doesn't grails take care of the differences for you? What is it you're trying to do? Read the "value" from TheDomainObject? Why doesn't list.value do it for you?

Comment: @marko that is not the issue, essentially any other value on the same array is returned with correct values, it us just the value result that is returned as null even though the value is INFO in the database

Comment: @dunnless instead of using "value" attribute, rename to something else and give a try i think "value" has some meaning when you do "list.rules.get(0).value"

Comment: @SajanChandran, this was not the issue, still aver changeing the names and property names, still same problem

Comment: seems like a part of the problem is that value is of type Object. changeing it to string makes at least string values work. cant see why this should be a problem